# Ruby matching subsets and displaying set(variable)

Tags: ruby, set, subset

```
feelings = Set["happy", "sad", "angry", "high", "low"]
euphoria = Set["happy", "high"]
dysphoria = Set["sad", "low"]
miserable = Set["sad", "angry"]

puts "How do you feel?"
str = gets.chomp
p terms = str.split(',')

if euphoria.proper_subset? feelings
  puts "You experiencing a state of euphoria."
else
  puts "Your experience is undocumented."
end

gets
```

How do I make euphoria a variable, such that if the corresponding string for miserable or dysphoria match & display the set name. Like #{Set}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing what you have, I think this is more like what you really want:

```
require 'set'

feelings = {
  euphoria: Set.new(%w[happy high]),
 dysphoria: Set.new(%w[sad low]),
 miserable: Set.new(%w[sad angry])
}

puts "What are you feeling right now?"
mood = Set.new gets.scan(/\w+/)
name, _ = feelings.find{ |_,matches| matches.subset?( mood ) }
if name
  puts "You are experiencing a state of #{name}"
else
  puts "Your experience is undocumented."      
end
```

Calling `gets.scan(/\w+/)` returns an array of strings. It's better than just `.split(',')` because it allows the user to put a space after commas (e.g. "sad, happy") or just use spaces (e.g. "sad happy").

As you already know, `Set[]` requires multiple arguments for it. Instead, we use `Set.new` which takes an array of values. Alternatively, you could have used `mood = Set[*gets.scan(/\w+/)]`, where the `*` takes the array of values and passes them as explicit parameters.

Also, I changed from `proper_subset?` to just `subset?`, because "happy,high" is not a *proper* subset of "happy,high", but it is a subset.

Comment: I want it not just for euphoria, but to display any of the three or if the user input matches.
`if states.include? feelings;
  puts "You experiencing a state of #{states}.";
else;
  puts "Your experience is undocumented.";
end`
i'm guessing;

Comment: @user1125021 Perhaps you looked at my code right before I edited it. Look again.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you think you want to put the name of a variable into another variable, you probably want a Hash instead:

```
states = {
    'euphoria'  => Set["happy", "high"],
    'dysphoria' => Set["sad",   "low"],
    'miserable' => Set["sad",   "angry"]
}
```

Then you can say things like:

```
which = 'euphoria' # Or where ever this comes from...
if states[which].proper_subset? feelings
  puts "You experiencing a state of #{which}."
else
  puts "Your experience is undocumented."
end
```

Comment: 'uninitialized constant Set (NameError)'


euphoria comes from terms, so
which = terms

Comment: @user1125021 You need `require "set"` to use the [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) library, since it part of the [Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/) (which is included with a Ruby installation, but not included in the runtime by default) and not [Core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core) (which is part of the runtime).

Comment: I get this error: undefined method proper_subset?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). i thought proper_subset? was predefined in the stdlib

also the `#{` in `#{which}."` is highlighted in my IDE

Comment: @user1125021: You're calling `proper_subset?` on `nil` so your `which` or `terms` (or whatever name you're using) is incorrect, you might want to add a `states.has_key?(which)` check.

Comment: `proper_subset?` is not part of the stdlib. It is part of `Set`. Again, you need to `require 'set'`.

Comment: So it works with `which = 'euphoria'`, but how do I make this such that it'll work with any of the states?

Comment: My guess is that you're doing `which = gets`, and typing in `euphoria` and pressing enter. If you do this, the result will be that `which == "euphoria\n"`. As a result, `states[which]` is returning `nil`, not the `Set` that you wanted. You need to use `chomp` to remove the newline after your input, e.g. `which = gets.chomp`. More importantly, you need to decide how to handle what the user types in.

Comment: However, in retrospect, I think this answer is on the wrong track from what you're looking for. See my answer to see if I've got it right.